# Is it possible to bind 2 axis to a single dataset in chart.js v2?

Tags: angularjs, layout, chart.js

I'm using angular-chart with a horizontal barchart. Now I need to add a second y-axis and bind it to the same dataset than the first y-axis.

The screenshot below shows my current progress. As you can see the second y-axis labels have a wrong alignment (red box). I believe this problem occurs since the dataset is not bound to this axis.

[image]

All my axis (x and y) are static an configured like shown below.

Please refer also to the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoMPaE) for this.

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            max: 100,
            min: -100,
            stepSize: 50
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        type: "category",
        "id": "y-axis-1",
        display: true,
        position: "left"
    }, {
        type: "category",
        "id": "y-axis-2",
        display: true,
        position: "right",
        ticks: {
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return $scope.labels2[index];
            }
        },
        gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
        }
    }]
}
```